# How to perform code first approach on visual studio 2022 in MacBook m1

Tags: macos, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages, entity-framework-migrations

How to add migration when working on razor pages with code first approach in visual studio 2022 on MacBook Air m1 because in tools we don’t get the option for package manager console from where we can add migration and update database

Anyone has the solution please share!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CLI commands instead. Open a terminal window, navigate to the directory containing your *.csproj* file and execute the commands from there.

Here's an example using the VS Code terminal: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tutorial/bakery7/migration#create-the-migration